# Prevent unauthorised download of an OTA installable application

Tags: ios, apache, security

On my Apache webserver, I‘d like to offer the possibility to download and install iOS applications „over the air“ (OTA).

To do so, I need a manifest.plist file and my .ipa. Both files need to be accessible.

My question is: How can we prevent unauthorized access to both the ipa and plist file?

I prefer not to use htaccess files, or, more exactly, authentication via htaccess. However, the manifest.plist file needs to include an absolute, fully qualified HTTPS url to the ipa.

I have no idea how we can limit the access to the file and prevent unauthorized download.

Comment: Which developer account are you using? Is it the Enterprise account or an Organization account?

Comment: @HAK Organization account, 99$ p.a.

Comment: For organizational account you can distribute your app to only the devices that are already added to your provision profile. Any other device wont be able to download n install the app.

Comment: Well, he won‘t be able to install the app, however, he is still able to download it.

Comment: use whatever authentication is provided by your web server so that people need to authenticate to download your app, or put the web server behind your firewall. There is nothing special here about App distribution; it is the same as securing any file on the web